# How do I check length of table rows associated with an ID/name and insert if less unless it's an update

Tags: mysql, node.js

I would like to make a request to MySQL that checks how large an owner's moderator list is, either update if existing (change level) for moderator, or insert if the moderator doesn't exist and only if below a limit of say 50 total moderators.

So far I'm using this but it seems bad SQL.

```
INSERT INTO `Moderator` (`owner`,`moderator`,`level`) 
VALUES(?, ?, ?) 
ON DUPLICATE 
KEY 
UPDATE level=?
```

Any ideas to improve this or how my tables work? I'd like to understand and be more efficient!

It would seem if I wanted to update a row prior it was efficient for an infinite row table (zero counting), but at this point with row limits (count) I'm thinking I need to stick to insert, delete and count between actions.

Is this efficient?